# php img src to php and database row?

Tags: php

I've searched hi and low for an answer to my queston, I'm attempting to call a php file with a script to check file size and output an image based of a database table of a certain type. Would anyone be able to help?
I'm getting a `undefined index for stocknr` when I run it even with `$row[stocknr]` as `$stocknr = $_GET['stocknr']`.

```
// assume connection
$query = "SELECT year, brand, model, class, stocknr, price, status, pic FROM 
stock WHERE class = 'ldv' ORDER BY brand ASC";
// Perform Query
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if (!$result) 
{
die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// test array
$product = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
for($j = 1; $j <= 30; $j++) {

    $product[$j]["model"] = "MODEL-$j";
    $product[$j]["pic"] = "PIC-$j";
    $product[$j]["price"] = "PRICE-$j";
}
// counter for cells
$i = 1;
// begin a table
echo '<table border="1">' . "\n";
foreach($product as $row)
// while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $title = $row['model'] ;
    $uppic = $row['pic'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    // for 1st, 6th, 11th etc record insert a tag for a new row
    if (($i == 1) or (($i - 1) % 4) == 0) {

        echo '<tr>' . "\n";
    }
    // insert a cell
    echo ("<td width=150 align=center>");
    echo ("<a href=../imagesize.php?scode=$uppic><img 
src=images/'$uppic'.jpg border=0 alt=Item $title</a>");
// $row[stocknr]? 
    echo ("<br><a href=\"details.php?stocknr=$row[stocknr]\">
          <span class=fs13>$title</span></a>");
    echo ("</td>");
    echo ("<tr height=150>");
    echo ("<a href=\"details.php?stocknr=$row[stocknr]\">
         <span class=sapri>$price</span></a>");
    // for 5th, 10th, 15th etc record insert a tag for end of the row
    if ((($i) % 5) == 0) {

        echo '</tr>';
    }

    // increment $i
    $i++;
 }
 }
 // filling row with empty cells 

 while(($i - 1) % 5 != 0) {

    // insert a blank cell
    echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';

    // increment $i
    $i++;

    // for 5th, 10th, 15th etc record insert a tag for end of the row
    if (($i - 1) % 5 == 0) {

        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
// end the table
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are overwriting the database output with your `foreach($product as $row)` line, which means that $row['stocknr'] ceases to exist.

As far as I can tell, you don't need that `foreach` loop and it can be removed, but I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the $product array.

As an aside, the `for($j = 1; $j <= 30; $j++) {` loop can move outside the `while` loop as it's just rewriting the same values for every row in the database.

**Edit:** does this do what you want?

```
$query = "SELECT year, brand, model, class, stocknr, price, status, pic 
FROM stock WHERE class = 'ldv' ORDER BY brand ASC";

$i = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if (!$result) {
    die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $title = $row['model'] ;
    $uppic = $row['pic'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $stock = $row['stocknr'];

    if (($i == 1) or (($i - 1) % 4) == 0) {
        echo '<tr>' . "\n";
    }

    echo "<td width=150 align=center>";
    echo "<a href=../imagesize.php?scode=$uppic><img src='images/$uppic.jpg' border='0' alt='Item $title'></a>";

    echo "<br><a href='details.php?stocknr=$stock'>
           <span class=fs13>$title</span></a>";
    echo "<br><a href='details.php?stocknr=$stock'>
     <span class=sapri>$price</span></a>";
    echo "</td>";

    // for 5th, 10th, 15th etc record insert a tag for end of the row
    if ((($i) % 5) == 0) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    $i++;
 }
 // filling row with empty cells 

while(($i - 1) % 5 != 0) {
     echo '<td> </td>';

     $i++;

    // for 5th, 10th, 15th etc record insert a tag for end of the row
    if (($i - 1) % 5 == 0) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I was trying to specify that $product variable was array so that the information specified with $product would be in the array, an array seemed like the only option to show an unlimited amount of images in a readable format. As far I'd read Foreach was a good option to specify that forwch product, so and so were to happen, but did not find much useful in the way of showinghow to use them with  while and if statements.

Comment: if you want to save the products in a new array for access later in the script, you can just add `$product[] = $row;` in the line after `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {`. But this will have the effect of loading the entire table into memory which you might want to avoid.  If the table is small relative to available memory you could just use `mysql_fetch_all` and skip the `while` loop.

Comment: great I will check to see if this works, probably not necessary to call up the table to take up memory.

Comment: Getting Undefined variable i, this being the $i = 1 and  while (($i - 1) %5 != 0) {

Comment: Also end up with 2 titles and prices without picture showing

Comment: I tidied up the code in the edit above. Try again. Really if you can avoid using tables for formatting then you should, and use CSS instead. Look it up. If the picture isn't showing it's probably an issue with your underlying data which would be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering is i can use imagsize.php in the src for the pic like `code` <img src='imagesize.php?w=250&h=280&img=$uppic'>? `code` Also does `code` $i `code` not need to be defined any longer and how does the counter know where to start? are they now from predetermined starting points?

Comment: and feeling dumb for not realising it meant just put code inside the `

Comment: Technically you should define `$i=0;` somewhere but if you don’t then php will auto-assign it to 0. And for the other question, yes you can but `imagesize.php` needs to return a valid image. Start a new question if you need help with that code.

Comment: had a "Undefined Index error" for 'i' so i guess i'll try the `i=0`